# Reading int with specific field width from stringstream

Tags: c++, width, field, istringstream, setw

I'm trying to read bytes in hex notation from a string. The bytes may or may unfortunately not be separated by whitespace, e.g. `"  00 ffab c  "` is a valid example and should result in 4 bytes read, 0x00, 0xff, 0xab and 0x0c. The problem is to skip whitespace but read only two adjacent digits, when present.

If the input were from a file, the task would be as easy as `while(fscanf(f, "%2d", &i) == 1) ...` because `sscanf` skips whitespace, the read position is tracked by the underlying `FILE`, and the maximum field width is only applied to the item read, not the raw input characters containing the whitespace. But the position tracking is not possible when reading from a  string; I need to use the `%n` format conversion specifier which stores the number of characters read so far by this invocation into the associated variable, e.g. `scanf(f, "%2d%n", &i, &readIncr)`, and manually maintain a read position by adding the respective increments.

This is somewhat cumbersome, hence I wanted to use `std::istringstream` which *does* keep track of a position in the underlying string.

But setting a width on the input stream does not have the desired (and expected) effect; below is a minimal demonstration; for simplicity I'm using decimal integers. Documentation and examples for an *input* field width are scarce.

Am I doing something wrong? I this use case simply not intended?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const char *s = "   1234";
  int i;
  istringstream is(s);

  if (is >> setw(2) >> i)
  {
    cout << "stringstream i: " << i << '\n';
  }

  if (sscanf(s, "%2d", &i) == 1)
  {
    cout << "scanf i: " << i << '\n';
  }
}
```

The output is (with g++ and MSVC)

```
$ g++ -Wall -o fieldwidth fieldwidth.cpp && ./fieldwidth
stringstream i: 1234
scanf i: 12
```

Comment: Good find of the dup. For some reason my google fu eluded me this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly cpp streams are far from perfect. AFAIK `std::setw` works only for reading strings. What you can do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const char *s = "   1234";
  std::string i;
  istringstream is(s);

  if (is >> setw(2) >> i)
  {
    cout << "stringstream i: " << std::stoi(i) << '\n';
  }

  int j;
  if (sscanf(s, "%2d", &j) == 1)
  {
    cout << "scanf i: " << j << '\n';
  }
}
```

And you get expected output:

```
stringstream i: 12
scanf i: 12
```